# True or false properties of the eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

1. $\varphi: \mathbb{C}^{3} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{3}$ an endomorphism with the property $\varphi^2=\varphi$ and $x \in \mathbb{C}^3$ arbitrary where $\varphi(x) \neq 0$. Then $\varphi(x)$ is an eigenvector of $\varphi$
2. $\varphi: \mathbb{C}^{3} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{3}$ an endomorphism with the property $\varphi^2=\varphi$ and $x \in \mathbb{C}^3$ arbitrary where $x \neq 0$. Then $x$ is an eigenvector of $\varphi$.

It's clear that the two statements above are projections in $\mathbb{C}^{3}$ but I don't know how to continue, should I search for an algebraic or a geometric solution?

Thank you for your help in advance

Comment: As $\varphi^2=\varphi \implies \varphi(\varphi-I)=0$. Applying $x$, we have $\varphi(\varphi-I)(x)=0$. As $\varphi(x)\neq 0 \implies (\varphi-I)(x)=0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. is true because if you apply $\phi$ to $\phi(x)$ you get
   $\phi(x)$.
2. Is true only if your map is $0$ or $1$. It is better to consider it geometrically, if the vector is not parallel to the subspace which is the range of your projection, its image is not a multiple of the vector unless the vector is in the kernel.

Answer (score 1):

1. This is always true, because $\varphi(\varphi x)=\varphi^2x=\varphi x$, therefore $\varphi x$ is an eigenvector of $\varphi$ with eigenvalue $1$.
2. This is not always true (take $x$ from the kernel of $\varphi$).

Edit: I was thinking of non-zero eigenvalues, elements of the kernel can be considered eigenvectors with eigenvalue $0$.

Comment: Any vector from the kernel or the range is an eigenvector. The thing is that there are no other eigenvectors unless the map is $0$ or $1$.

Comment: @Herrpeter since you've realised $\varphi$ is a projection, geometrically this means that the eigenvectors of $\varphi$ are (with eigenvalue $1$) exclusively elements of the range (what you're projecting on), while the other vectors in the space get collapsed to $0$. Therefore $x$ is an eigenvector if and only if $x \in \text{im}\varphi$.